# Do you have any informations about fossil-rich cherts from Scandinavia?

Tags: geology, sedimentology, petrology, paleontology

Me and some of my friends have found many rocks similar to these in central Europe - we believe that it is fossil-rich chert that originally comes from Scandinavia.

[image]
[image]
There are many interesting fossils like brachiopods and sea urchins.

We find many of them in southern Moravia - there are many sandpits with quartenary sediments (mostly sands and gravel) that were deposited by river Svitava. We think that these stones must had been transported by glaciers from Scandinavia and then deposited by rivers.

I have searched for this material on the internet and could not find any informations about its formation or deposition. Do you have any informations please ? Could you provide me some links, pdf-thesis or an explanation  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is information about the "Oslofeltet" ([Oslo-field](https://www.google.nl/search?q="oslo-field"+oslofeltet)) in Norway (dated to be from the Ordovicium period, 443 - 488 million years old). This is a concentrated field of of fossils. There is a [Sement museum](https://roykenbibliotek.no/cementmuseet/the-cement-museum/) ('cement') in a small place called [Slemmestad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slemmestad) where it is possible to view fossils from what was formerly an ocean bed. Geologicaly speaking, the entire area around Slemmestad is very interesting.